# How to automatically turn keyboard backlight on after suspend?

Tags: keyboard, suspend, backlight

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 on a Lenovo ThinkPad P72. When I suspend the laptop the keyboard backlight turns off, and remains off after I wake/resume.

How can I automatically turn the keyboard backlights back up to full without having to manually hit <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> twice?

Comment: Divide your problem into two problems: "How to turn backlight on" and "How can I make it happen at the right time". For the latter, The package `pm-utils` provides the `pm-action`, `pm-hibernate`, `pm-suspend` and `pm-suspend-hybrid` commands. They allow to trigger hard power management events by software. The `pm-tools`1 also provide script directories to hook-in other software when switching power (saving) states. (from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerManagement )